# How do I read data from a dynamically changing JSON file?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON file that contains information relating to the system - what LEDS and switches are on and off, etc. I then have a daemon that runs in the background and gathers this information and writes it to the JSON file. I'm reading the JSON file using AJAX and then displaying the information on a web page. The problem is that sometimes the daemon updates the file while the server is sending it over to the client, and then I get an error "CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH".

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried locking it long enough to read it? If the daemon behaves nicely, that should work. As an alternative, why not just retry the AJAX call if you get that error?

Comment: @Ed is that considered acceptable to just retry the transfer? I can get everything working if I do so, it's just that I get the content_length_mismatch warnings when I open the console in firefox and chrome. I'm new to web development so I'm not sure if that is okay, but it's easier to just go that route.

Comment: Sure; you have to handle errors somehow, anyway. You might want to code in a fault tolerance (no more than X errors every Y seconds, for example), but since you're just monitoring something, trying again is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Well you send wrong value for content length header. According to rfc2616

```
The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the entity-body,
in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, in the case of the HEAD
method, the size of the entity-body that would have been sent had the request
been a GET.
```

The solution here if you do not want to get this error is to pass correct value just before sending the output to the browser in your code.

Example:

```
<?php
// Beggining of the code start output buffering
ob_start();
// Process reading json file
// ......
// Ouput the content to the browser
echo $json;
// Set content-lenght header

header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
// Flush
ob_flush();
?>
```